# Can not login to Ask Ubuntu chat

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

This has been happening since a couple of weeks ago but I thought it was a temp thing. Now I really need to use the chat system and the problem still persists. Here is what is happening:

1. I go to the make Ask Ubuntu page and click on the **General Chat Room**
2. I can see what everyone is writing but when I click on LOGIN it sends me to an Stack Exchange page where it says is trying to login but stays there forever.
3. If I go back to the chat again just to make sure it logged in for some luck, I see am not logged in yet.

I am using Firefox 14 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Have you tried the alternate way? Clicking on the "log in via Stack Exchange" link on the login page?

Comment: Yeah. Already solved by a moderator via some cleaning cache thingy.

Comment: @balpha No clue what I did, I just kind of waved my hands. :P (Aka, I refreshed from his parent profile)

Comment: @balpha - How humble is jrg. He doesn't want to admit he is an awesome hacker ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just so if anybody has the same problem. Switching to Google Chrome worked. Also if this happens, ask a moderator for help. There was an issue with my account and now it works perfectly.